# How to insert into NatTable cell two text each with a different font?

Tags: java, nattable

I am trying to insert into a NatTable cell two texts, each with a different font type, as you can see in the image:

NatTable cell with two texts (each with a different font)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the RichTextCellPainter from the Nebula Extension and wrap the text with corresponding html tags for your fonts.